# How to find data from html and store it using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My HTML

```
<div class="product">
 <img src="#">
  <div class="priceStore">
   <p data="40">Item 1</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

How, using jQuery would I retrieve the data and store it?

My attempt:

```
$('.product').mousedown(function(event) {
    var x = $('.priceStore').parent().find(data);
    console.log(x);
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: what is this 'data' in the example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few different ways to write the selector but to get the value of an attribute you can use .attr()

Something like this works for this case

```
$('.product').mousedown(function(event) {
    var x = $('.priceStore p').attr('data');
    console.log(x);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Just as a follow up without making a load of other functions is there a way to find the data in the div of the one you clicked, if there is more than one? e.g. having 3 of the product classes with 3 different items and 3 different data stores. Using something like $(this)etc.

Comment: Yeah, I just wrote up a little demo to make sure but this seems to work: "var x = $(this).find('p').attr('data');"  That works if you paste the html a few times with other values for "data"

Comment: Here is a fiddle, click the products on the right and the data will show up in a div below them. http://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/8068/

Answer (score -1):

Personally I would rewrite your HTML as follows:

```
<div class="product">
 <img src="#">
  <div class="priceStore">
   <p id="data" data="40">Item 1</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

And then access the data element like this within your Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("data").getAttribute('data');
```

Advantages:
 - You don't need jQuery for this, it's basic javascript.
 - You can apply an identifier to multiple elements and access/manipulate data
 - Adding a second or third P tag won't break your code.

Ergo if you wanted to do so...

```
<div class="product">
 <img src="#">
  <div class="priceStore">
   <p id="apple" data="40">Item 1</p>
   <p id="orange" data="50">Item 2</p>
   <p id="grape" data="80">Item 3</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

You could then:

```
document.getElementById("apple").getAttribute('data');
document.getElementById("orange").getAttribute('data');
document.getElementById("grape").getAttribute('data');
```